# How to retrieve a JSON list within a javascript element with python?

Tags: javascript, python, json

I am trying to parse a json that I found in a website via python3.

[image]

This is the beginning of the snippet:

```
>>> jssnippet
'\n        var staticImpressions = staticImpressions || {};\n        staticImpressions[\'search_result_list\'] = [\n     {\n                "id": "16336937",...
```

This unfortunatelly failes:

```
data = json.loads(jssnippet, strict=False)
```

How can I access the variables in that list, e.g. id?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [In python, is there a way to extract a embedded json string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847747/in-python-is-there-a-way-to-extract-a-embedded-json-string)

Comment: Unfortunatly it does not work like in the solution within the referenced questions.